# Why is 'scrollHeight' in this example seen as 'undefined' and why did the iframe get an error while switching the html-file?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, height

This is my first question here, so sorry for mistakes...

I try to build a webseite with html, css and javascript on my Raspberry Pi with Apache2. So i script an automatic-iframe-height funktion, based on the content(from the html file). This html file changed by pressing a button.

So, i get this error from my explorer (chrome):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined
>       at HTMLIFrameElement.document.getElementById.onload

Here is my javascript:

```
function setIframeHeight(iframe_obj) {
 var d = document.getElementById(iframe_obj).onload = function() {
 var this_body = d.body,
    html = d.documentElement;

 var height = Math.max( this_body.scrollHeight, this_body.offsetHeight,
     html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
     // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
 obj.style.height = height + 'px';
 }
}
```

I tried a lot of variations of this code, but i get every time the same error.

Here is my html script (just a neckline):

```
<html lang="de">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptfunctions.js"></script>
 <link href="design.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
 <section>
  <iframe class="IframeClassSection" id="iframe-mainpage" src="/informationContainer/startseite.html" onload="setIframeHeight('iframe-mainpage');" scrolling="no"></iframe>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

And at last the css class for that iframe:

```
.IframeClassSection {
 display: block;
 background-color: orange;
 margin-left: 242px;
 margin-right: 200px;

 width: 718px;
 /* height: 2000px; */
 border: none;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

With this code i dont get an error while reloading a page, just when i try to set a new html location for a iframe, like this:

```
<input class="SteuerungObenButton" type="button" value="Startseite"       onclick="document.getElementById('iframe-mainpage').src='/informationContainer/startseite.html';" />
```

I search a whole day, but i cant find a solution which works ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bunch of issues here.

**#1** First and foremost, let's resolve the issue of your *Uncaught TypeError*. The error comes from **d** being equal to **document.getElementById(iframe_obj).onload** which is equal to the **onload function**. Since `Function` does not have a `body` or `documentElement` property, your **this_body** and **html** will always be `undefined` and thusly, `scrollHeight` and `offsetHeight` don't exist on `undefined` throwing the error you're seeing.

**#2** Once you resolve that issue, you'll find that an Iframe does not have a body or documentElement property either and you'll need to get the ContentWindow in the Iframe (note, you'll need to be on the same origin).

**#3** You have an `obj` at the bottom... Perhaps it's elsewhere in your code, but it's not in your example at all. It looks more like you want this to be the iframe itself, which is `d`.

So, to fix it completely, give this a shot:

```
function setIframeHeight(iframeStringId) {
  var d = document.getElementById(iframeStringId);
  d.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var this_body = d.contentWindow.document.body;
    var html = d.contentWindow.document.documentElement;

    var height = Math.max(this_body.scrollHeight, this_body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    d.style.height = height + 'px';
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, if i push a button, it set the right height now, but (just) when i reload the page, the height set to static value... didnt the onload event work for refresh the page?